# Android soft-keyboard will not display after enabling youtube video to return from full screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, fullscreen

My app makes heavy use of youtube videos to answer questions about products and installs of these products. Just for context, I am a full stack web developer and have only a month of java/android studio development under my belt. The app in written in only javascript and css and i use the android webview to display it as an app. Currently, I have a web chrome client that hides the full youtube video and also display the full screen youtube video. Once one video is full screen and then back to normal view, if i tap on a input field the key board does not display and i get the message in the debugger.

"I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1928 bytes, containing 1 windows, 5 views"

Thinking it is from the web chrome client hiding the custom view.

thinking that the answer is to check if the view is the keyboard, and not execute the 
onHideCustomView(); but i am not exactly sure this is the case or if i am just doing something stupid.

below is the code of most of the app or enough for context.

Thank you guys for taking the time to help me out.

Also any pointers if i can improve this process would be appreciated as well.

Thank You :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    myWebView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(myWebView);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("url");

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);


}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        String webUrl = myWebView.getUrl();
        if (webUrl.indexOf("directory/url") < 0){

                myWebView.loadUrl("url");


            return true;
        }else {
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:android();");
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}


private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    MyChrome() {}



    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had to clear the focus on the web view

```java
public void onHideCustomView()
{
    ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
    this.mCustomView = null;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
    setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
    this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
    this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    myWebView.clearFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the focus of webview it worked.

```
 public void onHideCustomView()
    {

        ((FrameLayout)MainUI.this.getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        MainUI.this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        MainUI.this.setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;

        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        webView.clearFocus();
  }
```